# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs android 12

Tags: android

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

In my project file,

it was
compileSdkVersion 30
and
targetSdkVersion 30

android {
compileSdkVersion 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aaasss.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
```

I updated it and also updated
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.0'
to
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'

When I export the project, I get the error message
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
Note that I have modified
android:exported="true">

Comment: open your manifest file and below it you have "merged manifest" tab - open it and inspect errors/warnings

Comment: Is there any video explanation